# UWP - Default language is an Arabic language (ar-sa) but while running is British (en-GB)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

The default language for the UWP (Universal Windows Platform) app is set to Arabic (ar-sa). However, when I run the application, it displays the British English language (en-GB) instead.

In the first image, it shows the setting to set the default language in the UWP app.

In the second image, it shows that the app language default is set to British English.

Comment: Have you installed the Arabic language resource in the target device? And another question is that have you created a Resources.resw file for the Arabic language in your app?

Comment: Yes, I have installed Arabic language, at the first time I did not have the problem but suddenly it was changed to en-GB.

Comment: Have you set the ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride Property in your app?